# Hierarchy facets using Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using aggregations/sub-aggregations to navigate through the facets as hierarchy. This holds good as long as a single row contains only one value for each attribute. How can I achieve a proper hierarchy filtering for the below case.

Let us consider the following three rows of course. Each of the course is available in different locations

```
Course ID,  Contintent, Country , Location

Course 1    Asia ,India, Hyd
            Asia ,India, Bangalore                       

Course 2    Asia ,India, Hyd
            Asia ,Pak, Hyd         

Course 3    Europe, Germany , Brussels
            Asia,India,hyd
```

Once if I navigate through the facets with Asia as a selected facet, then in the Country I should not have Germany coming as a facet. Only Countries from Asia should get listed.
As of now with multi valued data it just brings Germany as well in to consideration.

Is there a way I can implement this filtering considering the real hierarchy?

Comment: Please post your current code or query

Comment: can you post the sample document?